# C# and XAML Windows Store App How change textBlock data?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Can I change the values of textBlockZona in DataTemplate?
I need to create a dynamic header list, how can I change myTEXT content in the code?

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeadTemplate">
            <Grid
                Width="745" Height="61" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" Background="Transparent">

                <Grid
                    x:Name="gridZona" Width="122" Height="36" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="ZonaButton" Fill="#FF2994FF" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="textBlockZona" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"
                        Text="MYTEXT"
                        TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition" />
                </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ViewTemplate">
            <local:PosItemViewer />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>

    <ListView        x:Name="RigheView" Grid.Row="1" Width="744" Height="867" Margin="10,203,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                ContainerContentChanging="RigheView_ContainerContentChanging"
                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeadTemplate}"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ViewTemplate}"
                SelectionMode="None" />
```

Comment: attention to
HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeadTemplate}"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should bind the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to a property of the type `T` in the `IEnumerable<T>` that you have set as the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlockZona" Text="{Binding YourTextProperty}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition" />
```

Then you can simply set this property to any string you want and have the `TextBlock` being automatically updated provided that the type `T` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx.

This is the only correct way of doing this. You don't modify a *template* that you have defined in your XAML markup programmatically.

**Edit:** A `TextBlock` in the `HeaderTemplate` should be bound to a property in the view model, i.e. the `DataContext` of the `ListView` itself, the same way.

Comment: But header properties have nothing to do with the element list.

attention to
HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeadTemplate}"

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Could you give me an small example?

Comment: I understand, and I solved the problem thanks to your help.

Comment: ok thanks again  ;)